# How to split texts with two delimiters on the same line in a .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, split

I have a .txt called readings, it has the following data in it:

```
-10,3NW,15cm,4:38
5,15SW,8mm,2:8
8,8ENE,2mm,:25
-5,0,7cm,1
-3,0,3mm
```

Where the first position represents the Temperature, speed, precipitation and time(hours and minutes)

I want to split the string with `tokens = line.split(":");` only if the fourth token exists.
My code for splitting the string without doing any splits with the delimiter `:` is:

```
    try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("readings.txt"));

        line = input.readLine();
        while (line != null ) {
            tokens = line.split(",");

            temperature = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim());

            tokens[1] = tokens[1].trim();
            separation = firstNonNumericPosition(tokens[1]);




            if (separation == 0 || (separation < 0 && Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) != 0)) {
                speed = -1;
            } else {
                if (separation < 0) {
                    speed = 0;
                    direction = "";
                } else {
                    numeric = tokens[1].substring(0, separation);
                    speed = Integer.parseInt(numeric.trim());
                    direction = tokens[1].substring(separation).trim();
                }

                if (tokens.length > 2) {
                    tokens[2] = tokens[2].trim();
                    separation = firstNonNumericPosition(tokens[2]);
                    if (separation <= 0) {
                        precipitation = -1;
                    } else {
                        numeric = tokens[2].substring(0, separation);
                        precipitation = Integer.parseInt(numeric.trim());
                        unit = tokens[2].substring(separation).trim();
                    }
                } else {
                    precipitation = 0;
                    unit = "";
                }

            }


            if (speed < 0 || precipitation < 0) {
                System.out.println("Error in input: " + line);
            } else {
                readings[size] = new Reading(temperature, speed, direction,
                        precipitation, unit.equalsIgnoreCase("cm"));
                size++;
            }




            line = input.readLine();
        }

        input.close();



    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ar){
        System.out.println(ar.getMessage());
    }
```

I tried using this logic but it gave an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException of 3.

```
if(tokens.length > 3) {
   tokens = line.split(":");
   hours =Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].trim());
   minutes =Integer.parseInt(tokens[4].trim());
}
```

How is it possible to split it if the fourth token exists?

These are just parts of my code, any further explanation on what the question means(in case I'm not clear enough) could be provided. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you splitting by commas?

Comment: i'm also splitting by commas. its in the code on the 6th line @michaelsnowden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class. Much easier to handle tokens.

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line,":");
```

You can easily check :

```
string firstToken = tokens.nextToken();  //capture out first token
if(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){  //check if 2nd token is there
    StringTokenizer subTokens = new StringTokenizer(firstToken, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(tokens.length > 3) {
   tokens = line.split(":");
   hours =Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].trim());
   minutes =Integer.parseInt(tokens[4].trim());
}
```

I think you meant to write something like this:

```
if (tokens.length > 3) {
    String[] time = tokens[3].split(":");
    String hoursString = time[0];
    if (hoursString.length() > 0) {
        hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursString);
    }
    if (time.length > 1) {
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(time[1]);
    }
}
```